# How to send the user to different pages when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: php

```
<form entype="multipart/form-data" method="GET" action="">
          <div class="box-body">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" name="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan kata kunci">
          </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <input value="1" type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="queryexp" />
            Gunakan query expansion
          </div>
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Hi hello I want to ask a simple question. The code above is **search.php**,
I want to send the form to a different page based on if the checkbox is checked or not. If the checkbox is checked it will be directed to **resqueryexp.php**, but if not it will be directed to **result.php**

I have been trying to adding this code but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['queryexp'])){

    header("Location: resqueryexp.php");

}else{

   header("Location: result.php");
}?>
```

Sorry for my bad English and Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the php code is in `search.php` file and the other files are in the same directory. correct?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['submit'] )) {
  if ($_GET['queryexp'] == 1 ){
     header("Location: resqueryexp.php");
     exit;
}
else 
{
     header("Location: result.php");
     exit;
  }
} 
?>
<html>
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="GET" action="">
              <div class="box-body">
                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Masukkan kata kunci">
              </div>
              <div class="box-body">
                <input value="1" type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="queryexp" />
                Gunakan query expansion
              </div>
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

This code won't run here at SO, but this is how it may work on your webserver.  The important part is to test if the form was submitted. So, in this case, I gave the submit button the name of "submit" and then tested with PHP to see if the form was even submitted.  If the form is submitted and if the checkbox is checked, the redirect via header() occurs.  Otherwise, if the checkbox is unchecked, then the redirect occurs via header to result.php.  You may avoid header issues by making an adjustment to you PHP.ini settings and adding this line "output_buffering = On".

Note: usually a form with the enctype attribute having a value of "multipart/form-data" involves submitting a file and under such circumstances the method attribute should be a POST request instead of a GET; see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, the form is also bring the $_GET['keyword'], so the url should be http://../resqueryexp.php?keyword='something' if checked or http://../result.php?keyword='something'

Comment: @JuliAndika You're welcome.  Every form element that has a name attribute will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php